# hide password in gitlab pipeline

Tags: ssh, gitlab, passwords, gitlab-ci

i have gitlab pipeline in it  try to ssh to a remote machine , i wrote machine password as variable in setting -> ci-cd -> variable i masked and protected it  but i notice admins , owner , and maintainers can see the value of password how i solve that without need to external solution (like HashiCorp Vault, AWS Secrets Manager, or CyberArk. or other solution like that)

try to save password of remote machine in gitlab to use in gitlab pipeline and keep it secret from admins and other maintainer so expect i can do that

Comment: You cannot hide things from a Gitlab admin or maintainer. The very fact that this is sensitive this should be managed using a secrets manager solution if you want only authorized people have access to it. Gitlab cannot hide things from admin/maintainers.